# C#, Firebird, load .fdb file into RAM?

Tags: c#, firebird, ram

If i have c# application and using it with embedded firebird, can I load this .FDB file, database file not on disk, but only into memory, into RAM?
I need it to be encrypted, decrypt it but not save decrypted on disk, because simple reset could allow someone to have decrypted file, so i want it to load into memory, into RAM, to make it maybe not impossible but harder.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you read the file without saving it anywhere, it is loaded into the memory.

Comment: Save it into any variable. That's RAM right there for you.

Comment: AFAIK Firebird itself does not have such support, but there may be a suitable [Ram Drive / Ram Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_RAM_drive_software) tool available in Windows - however, I suspect an X/Y problem, so only view this as a "some possible approach that meets the requirements as stated", not that the requirements are good.

Comment: I want to have it (fdb database file) encrypted, protected. If it is on disk, somebody just will do reboot and have files on disk decrypted. But in ram it would be harder. Or maybe are there some flag like FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE flag in createfile? but would it work with hard machine reboot?

Comment: You might be better off to use an encrypted partition (eg with TrueCrypt) and have the Firebird server work as normal.